# Want to display values in proper order on PDF Document

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

I am getting the Equipment/Service Level Detail Table values but it"s not proper order. Want to display X1,X2,X3,Y1,Y2,Y3....here displaying X1,X2,Y1,X3,Y2,Y3 in PDF , could you help me?

VF page :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .custPopup{
        background-color: white;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        z-index: 9999;
        left: 50%;
        padding:1px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: -250px;
        top:100px;
    }
    .popupBackground{
        background-color:black;
        opacity: 0.20;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 9998;
    }

</style>

<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryFiles, 'js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js')}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doDone() {
        //alert('Test alert');
        $('#doneBtn').show('slow');
        $('#cancelBtn, #ppActionStatus').hide('slow');
        window.open('/{!q.Id}','_self' );
    }
</script>

<apex:sectionHeader title="Quote {!q.Name}" subtitle="Document Creation - Select Templates"/>
<div>
    <apex:outputPanel id="DocGenApplet-hover-link-panel"
        styleClass="my-hover-panel">
    </apex:outputPanel>
</div>
<apex:form id="frm">   
  <input type="hidden" id="pdfNames" value="{!fileNamesAsString}"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="templateIds" value="{!templateIdsAsString}"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="subreportIds" value="{!subreportIdsAsString}"/>
  <apex:pageMessages id="mess" showDetail="true" />

  <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!canbeEdited}">
    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;padding-left:40%;font-size:120%;" value="Go To Step"></apex:outputLabel> 
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:commandButton value="2"  style=" height:25px; width:30px; text-align:center;"
        action="{!qd_2}" title="Quote Details" />    
        <apex:commandButton value="3" style="height:25px;width:30px;text-align:center;"
        action="{!qd_3}" title="Contract Parameters"/>

        <apex:commandButton value="4" style="height:25px;9px;width:30px;text-align:center; "
        action="{!qd_4}" title="Select Equipment"/>    
        <apex:commandButton value="5" style="height:25px;width:30px;text-align:center ;"
        action="{!qd_5}" title="Select Services"/>    
        <apex:commandButton value="6" style="height:25px;9px;width:30px;text-align:center ;"
        action="{!qd_6}" title="Jobsite Variables"/>    
        <apex:commandButton value="7" style="height:25px;width:30px;text-align:center;"
        action="{!qd_7}" title="Add labor Mat’l & Sub"/>    
        <apex:commandButton value="8" style="height:25px;width:30px;text-align:center;;"
        action="{!qd_8}" title="Final Pricing"/>    
        <apex:commandButton value="9" style="height:25px;width:30px;text-align:center; color:red; background:yellow;"
        action="{!qd_9}" title="Create Doc"/>
    </apex:pageblockButtons> 
</apex:pageblock> 

<apex:pageBlock title="Templates">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons id="btns">
        <apex:commandButton value="Previous" status="bottomStatus"
                action="{!dg_previous}"
                title="Previous"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Generate" action="{!generate}" status="stts" disabled="{!NOT(hasSelectedRecords)}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true" action="{!doCancel}"/>
        <apex:actionStatus startText="Please wait ..." id="stts" startStyle="color:red">
            <apex:facet name="start">
                   <apex:outputPanel style="color:red"> <img src="/img/loading.gif"/> Please wait ... </apex:outputPanel>                       
            </apex:facet>                 
        </apex:actionStatus>                    
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" columns="1" id="langTable" rendered="{!multiLanguage}">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:selectList value="{!defaultLanguage}" size="1">                               
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!languages}"/> 
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"
                                    action="{!languageChange}" 
                                    rerender="frm"/>
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:outputText value="Generated document will be attached to Notes And Attachments" rendered="{!isWordFormat}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!templates}" var="t" id="pbTable">
        <apex:column headerValue="Select" style="width:40px;">
            <apex:facet name="header">
              <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!allChecked}" disabled="{!!hasEnabledRecords}"> 
                <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" 
                                    action="{!CheckAll}" 
                                    status="stts"
                                    rerender="frm, pbTable"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
                                    action="{!CheckAll}" 
                                    status="stts"
                                    rerender="frm, pbTable"/>
              </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:facet>

            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!t.selected}" disabled="{!t.disabled}">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" 
                                    action="{!updateOkBtn}" 
                                    status="stts"
                                    rerender="frm"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
                                    action="{!updateOkBtn}" 
                                    status="stts"
                                    rerender="frm"/>
            </apex:inputCheckbox>               
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Name">
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!t.obj.Required__c}">
                <div class="requiredInput">
                    <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!t.obj.Name}" style="{!t.style}"/>
                </div>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:outputText value="{!t.obj.Name}" style="{!t.style}"
                                rendered="{!NOT(t.obj.Required__c)}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Type">
            <apex:outputText value="{!t.obj.Type__c}" style="{!t.style}"/>              
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Status">
            <apex:outputText value="{!t.message}" style="{!t.style}"/>              
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Generated Date">
            <apex:outputText value="{!t.generatedDate}" style="{!t.style}"/>                
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>

    <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" columns="1" id="additionCbxTable">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:selectList value="{!format}" size="1">                                
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="word" itemLabel="Word"/>  
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="pdf" itemLabel="PDF"/> 
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
                                    rerender="frm"/>
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:outputText value="Generated document will be attached to Notes And Attachments" rendered="{!isWordFormat}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Quote Last Modified Date"/>
            <apex:outputText value="{!quoteLastModifiedDate}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>  
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:outputPanel id="tstpopup">
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!showApplet}"/>
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!showApplet}">
        <apex:pageBlock id="appletBlock">
            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!showApplet}" style="background-color: #ddb929; color:white; text; white-space:nowrap; font-weight:bold;">
                Please wait while document generator is working...                      
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="text-align: center; margin: 10px;">

                <apex:actionStatus startText="Please wait ..." id="stts" startStyle="color:red">
                    <apex:facet name="start">
                        <apex:outputPanel style="color:red"> <img src="/img/loading.gif"/> Please wait ... </apex:outputPanel>                                                  
                    </apex:facet>                 
                </apex:actionStatus>                                                

                <applet id="docgenApplet" code = "com.salesoptimizer.sforce.applets.DocGenApplet" 
                        archive = "{!URLFOR($Resource.DocGenApplet, 'jrv.jar')},
                        {!URLFOR($Resource.DocGenJasper, 'jasperreports-4.1.2.jar')},           
                        {!URLFOR($Resource.DocGenJasper, 'commons-collections-2.1.1.jar')},         
                        {!URLFOR($Resource.DocGenJasper, 'commons-digester-1.7.jar')},
                        {!URLFOR($Resource.DocGenJasper, 'iText-2.1.7.jar')},       
                        {!URLFOR($Resource.DocGenJasper, 'commons-logging-1.0.4.jar')},
                        {!URLFOR($Resource.DocGenFonts, 'jasperreports-fonts-4.1.2.jar')}"
                        WIDTH = "490" HEIGHT = "60">
                    <param name="quoteId" value="{!q.id}"/>
                    <param name="quoteName" value="{!q.Name}"/>

                    <param name="pdfNames" value="{!fileNamesAsString}"/>
                    <param name="templateIds" value="{!templateIdsAsString}"/>
                    <param name="subreportIds" value="{!subreportIdsAsString}"/>

                    <param name="sessionId" value="{!$Api.Session_ID}"/>
                    <param name="partnerUrl" value="{!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_200}"/>
                    <param name="IMG_ROOT_DEFAULT" value="{!URLFOR($Resource.ABUMDocGenImages)}"/>
                    <param name="IMG_ROOT" value="{!IMG_ROOT}"/>
                    <param name="merge" value="{!mergeReports}"/>
                    <param name="overwrite" value="true"/>
                    <param name="saveAndEmailUrl" value="{!saveAndEmailUrl}"/>
                    <param name="docgenAction" value="{!abumAction}"/>
                    <param name="format" value="{!format}"/>
                    <param name="cache_option" value="no"/>
                     <param name="keepalive" value="true"/>
                </applet>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="text-align: center; margin: 10px; white-space:nowrap;">
                <span id="doneBtn" style="display: none;">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Ok, Close it"
                        title="Please click AFTER reports are generated"
                        action="{!doDonePopup}"
                        status="popstts"
                        immediate="true"
                    />
                </span>

                <span id="cancelBtn">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel"
                        action="{!doCancelPopup}"
                        status="popstts"
                        immediate="true"
                    />
                </span>

                <span id="ppActionStatus" style="color:red">
                   <img src="/img/loading.gif"/> Please wait ...                                            
                </span>

            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
 </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
<apex:relatedList subject="{!Quote}" list="NotesAndAttachments"/>
<apex:relatedList subject="{!Quote}" list="QuoteDocuments"/>
```

Apex Controller :

```
public with sharing class SADocGenController {
private static String namespacePrefix = 'notset';
public String abumAction {get;set;}
public String format {get;set;}

public class DocGenTemplate
{
    public DGReport__c obj {get;set;}
    public Boolean selected {get;set;}
    public Boolean generated {get;set;}
    public String generatedDate {get;set;}
    public Boolean disabled {get;set;}
    public Boolean isOutdated {get;set;}
    public String message {get;set;}
    public String style {get;set;}
    public List<DGSubreport__c> subreports {get;set;}
}

public Quote q {get;set;}
public String quoteLastModifiedDate {set;get;}
public List<SelectOption> templateOptions {get;set;}

public String reportId {get;set;}
public List<DocGenTemplate> templates {get;set;}

public Boolean allChecked { get; set; }
public Boolean hasEnabledRecords { get; set; }
public Boolean hasSelectedRecords { get; set; }
public Boolean selectedOne { get; set; }
public Boolean hasMergedPdfGenerated { get; set; }
public Boolean canbeEdited{ get; set; }

public Boolean mergeReports { get; set; }
//public Boolean overwriteOld { get; set; }

public String mergeLabel { get; set; }
public String mergeStyle { get; set; }
public String IMG_ROOT {get;set; }
public String defaultLanguage {get;set; }
public Boolean multiLanguage { get; set; }
/*  Public boolean butn8_bool{get;set;}
public String buttntype{get;set;} */

public Boolean showApplet { get; set; }

public Boolean isWordFormat {
    get {
        return format == 'word';
    }
}
/*    public void cust_edit(){
   //Value= true;
   if(buttntype=='buttn9'){
       butn8_bool=false;
   }
}  */
public void checkAll() {
    Integer n = 0;
    for(DocGenTemplate dgt : templates){
        if (!dgt.disabled) {
            dgt.selected = allChecked;
        }
        if(dgt.selected) n++;

    }
    selectedOne = n == 1; 
    hasSelectedRecords = n > 0;    
}

public void languageChange() {
    loadTemplateOptions();
}  

public void updateOkBtn() {  
    Integer n = 0;
    for(DocGenTemplate dgt : templates){
        if (dgt.selected) {
            if(dgt.selected) n++;
        }
    }
    selectedOne = n == 1; 
    hasSelectedRecords = n > 0;
}

public List<SelectOption> getLanguages() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = DGReport__c.Language__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
    }   
    return options;
}

public String getTemplateIdsAsString(){
    String tIds = '';
    for(DocGenTemplate dgt: templates)
        if(dgt.selected) {
            tIds += dgt.obj.DocumentId__c + ';';
        }
    return tIds;
}

/*Delimeter between subreports related to one report ':' between key and value '?'*/
public String getSubreportIdsAsString(){
    String srIds = '';
    for(DocGenTemplate dgt: templates)
        if(dgt.selected) {
            if (dgt.subreports.size() > 0) {
                for(DGSubreport__c dgp: dgt.subreports) {
                    srIds += '' + dgp.SubreportNumber__c + '?' + dgp.DocumentId__c + ':';
                }
            } else {
                srIds += 'NA';
            }
            srIds += ';';
        }
    return srIds;
}

public String getFileNamesAsString(){
    String tNames = '';
    for(DocGenTemplate dgt: templates)
        if(dgt.selected) {
            if (isWordFormat) {
                tNames += dgt.obj.FileName__c + '.docx;';
            } else {
                tNames += dgt.obj.FileName__c + '.pdf;';
            }
        }

    return tNames;
}

private Set<String> selectedTemplates = new Set<String>();

public SADocGenController(ApexPages.StandardController stdc) {
    this.templates = new List<DocGenTemplate>();
    this.templateOptions = new List<SelectOption>();        

    this.q = ABUMDAO.getQuote(stdc.getId());    
    this.quoteLastModifiedDate = q.lastModifiedDate.format();
    this.mergeReports = true;
    //this.overwriteOld = false;
    this.format = 'pdf';

    this.IMG_ROOT = '';
/*  buttntype=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('buttntype');  */
    ABUM__c qs = ABUM__c.getInstance();
    if(qs != null) {
        this.IMG_ROOT = qs.IMG_ROOT__c;
        this.defaultLanguage = qs.DocGen_Default_Language__c;
        if (String.isBlank(this.defaultLanguage))
            this.defaultLanguage = 'English';
        this.multiLanguage = qs.DocGen_Multi_Language__c;
    }

}

public PageReference doCancel() {
    return new ApexPages.PageReference('/' + q.Id).setRedirect(true);
}

public PageReference doDonePopup() {
    showApplet = false;
    return new ApexPages.PageReference('/' + q.Id).setRedirect(true);
}

public PageReference doCancelPopup() {
    showApplet = false;
    return null;
}

public PageReference saveAndEmail() {
    this.abumAction = 'saveAndEmail';
    return generateImpl();
}

public PageReference generate() {
    this.abumAction = 'save';
    return generateImpl();
}

public String getSaveAndEmailUrl() {
    String urlStr = '/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?';

    if (q.ContactId != null) {
        urlStr += 'p2_lkid=' + q.ContactId
                    + '&'
                    + 'rtype=003'
                    + '&'
                    + 'p24=' + q.Contact.Email
                    + '&';

    }

    urlStr += 'p3_lkid=' + q.Id
            + '&'
            + 'retURL=%2F' + q.Id
            + '&'
            + 'doc_id=';

    return urlStr;
}

public PageReference generateImpl() {
    selectedTemplates.clear();
    Map<String, Integer> selectedTemplatesCounter = new Map<String, Integer>(); 
    for(DocGenTemplate dgt: templates) {
        if (dgt.selected) {
            Integer counter = 0;
            if (selectedTemplatesCounter.containsKey(dgt.obj.Type__c)) {
                counter = selectedTemplatesCounter.get(dgt.obj.Type__c);
            } 
            counter++;
            selectedTemplatesCounter.put(dgt.obj.Type__c, counter);
        }
        if(!dgt.selected && dgt.obj.Required__c) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(
                new ApexPages.Message(
                ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
                'Not all required documents are selected', 
                'Please select all reqired documents.'));
            return null;
        }
        if(dgt.selected) {
            selectedTemplates.add(dgt.obj.Id);
        }
    }

    //You can select any types of document templates but no more than one of each type
    String moreThanOneTypeSelectedMsg = '';
    Boolean moreThanOneTypeSelected = false;
    for (String key : selectedTemplatesCounter.keySet()) {
        if (selectedTemplatesCounter.get(key) > 1) {
            moreThanOneTypeSelectedMsg += key + ': ' + selectedTemplatesCounter.get(key);
            moreThanOneTypeSelected = true; 
        }
    }
    if (moreThanOneTypeSelected) {          
        ApexPages.addMessage(
            new ApexPages.Message(
            ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
            'Multiple documents of the same type (' + moreThanOneTypeSelectedMsg + ') have been selected', 
            'Please select no more than one document of each type.'));           
        return null;
    } 


    if (selectedTemplates.isEmpty()) {          
        ApexPages.addMessage(
            new ApexPages.Message(
            ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
            'Template is not selected', 
            'Please select some template.'));           
        return null;
    } 
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('templateIds', getTemplateIdsAsString());
    showApplet = true;
    return null;//return Page.SADocGen;
}

private QuoteDocument findQuoteDocumentByName(String testStr,  List<QuoteDocument> atts) {
    for (QuoteDocument a : atts) {
        if (testStr == a.Name)
            return a;
    }
    return null;
}

private Boolean checkForOutdate(QuoteDocument tA) {
    return q.lastModifiedDate.getTime() > tA.CreatedDate.getTime();
}

public String calculateStyle(Boolean isDocGenerated, Boolean isDocOutdated) {
    String tStyle = '';
    if (isDocGenerated)
        tStyle += 'font-weight:bold;';
    if (isDocOutdated)
        tStyle += 'color: red;';
    return tStyle; 
} 

public void loadTemplateOptions() {
    templates.clear();
    templateOptions.clear();

    hasSelectedRecords = false;
    selectedOne = false;

    List<QuoteDocument> atts = [SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate FROM QuoteDocument WHERE QuoteId =: q.Id];
    String qt_id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    if(qt_id!=null){
        Quote quot=[Select id,Approval_Status__c from Quote where id=:qt_id];
        if(quot.Approval_Status__c=='Approved'){
            canbeEdited=true;
        }
    }
    hasEnabledRecords = false;
    Double contractTerm = q.Escalation_Years__c;
    boolean checkedJobsites = [select count() From QuoteLineItem Where QuoteId = :q.id AND (Line_Type__c = 'Standard Job Site Variable' OR Line_Type__c = 'User Defined Job Site Variable')] > 0;
    for(DGReport__c dgto: [SELECT id, Name, Required__c, DocumentId__c, FileName__c, SortOrder__c, Type__c, Disabled__c, Checked_by_default__c,
                            (SELECT id, DocumentId__c, SubreportNumber__c from Subreports__r where Contract_Term__c = :contractTerm or Contract_Term__c = null) 
                             FROM DGReport__c
                             WHERE Language__c =: defaultLanguage and (Job_Type__c includes (:q.Job_Type__c) or Job_Type__c='') 
                                    and (Check_Jobsite_Variables__c = :checkedJobsites or Check_Jobsite_Variables__c = null) 
                             ORDER BY SortOrder__c LIMIT 100])
    {
            DocGenTemplate dgt = new DocGenTemplate();
            dgt.obj = dgto;
            dgt.disabled = dgto.Disabled__c;
            dgt.generated = false;
            dgt.isOutdated = false;
            dgt.style = '';

            QuoteDocument tA = findQuoteDocumentByName(dgto.FileName__c + '.pdf', atts); 
            if(tA != null) {
                dgt.message = 'Document generated';
                dgt.disabled = true;
                dgt.generated = true;
                dgt.generatedDate = tA.CreatedDate.format();
                dgt.isOutdated = checkForOutdate(tA);
                dgt.style = calculateStyle(dgt.generated, dgt.isOutdated);
            } else {
                dgt.message = 'Not generated';
                hasEnabledRecords = true;
            }
            dgt.selected = dgto.Checked_by_default__c;
            dgt.subreports = new List<DGSubreport__c>();
            for(DGSubreport__c dgp: dgto.Subreports__r)
            {
                dgt.subreports.add(dgp);
            }
            templates.add(dgt);
            SelectOption so = new SelectOption(dgto.Id, dgto.Name);
            templateOptions.add(so);
            if (dgt.selected == true) {
                    hasSelectedRecords = true;
            }
    }
}

public PageReference dg_previous() {
    PageReference pr = Page.SAFinalPricing;
    pr.getParameters().put('Id', q.Id);
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}


public PageReference qd_2() {
    PageReference pr = Page.SAQuoteDetails;
    pr.getParameters().put('Id', q.Id);
    pr.getParameters().put('buttntype', 'buttn2');
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
public PageReference qd_3() {
    PageReference pr = Page.SAContractParams;
    pr.getParameters().put('Id', q.Id);
    pr.getParameters().put('buttntype', 'buttn3');
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
public PageReference qd_4() {
    PageReference pr = Page.SAAddEquipment;
    pr.getParameters().put('Id', q.Id);
    pr.getParameters().put('buttntype', 'buttn4');
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
public PageReference qd_5() {
    PageReference pr = Page.SAAddServices;
    pr.getParameters().put('Id', q.Id);
    pr.getParameters().put('buttntype', 'buttn5');
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
public PageReference qd_6() {
    PageReference pr = Page.SAJobSite;
    pr.getParameters().put('Id', q.Id);
    pr.getParameters().put('buttntype', 'buttn6');
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
public PageReference qd_7() {
    PageReference pr = Page.SAAdditional;
    pr.getParameters().put('Id', q.Id);
    pr.getParameters().put('buttntype', 'buttn7');
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}

public PageReference qd_8() {
    PageReference pr = Page.SAFinalPricing;
    pr.getParameters().put('Id', q.Id);
    pr.getParameters().put('buttntype', 'buttn8');
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}

 public PageReference qd_9(){
    return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried to format you code but the formatting puts the content over the 30,000 character limits. Please cut down the Visualforce and Apex to the relevant sections and use the {} button to format those.

Answer (score 1):

I see a issues with what you've posted. Before trying to fix your existing code, I recommend you take a look at [Best Practices for Rendering PDFs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm). I think you'll quickly discover that you're using certain Apex call outs in your code that are UNSAFE to use in a PDF.

It appears that you're attempting to render the PDF's in an `<apex:outputPanel>` using some kind of applet. I see where you have active content in that panel like `<apex:actionStatus>` (known to be UNSAFE) along with other `<apex:CommandButton>` callouts (also known to be UNSAFE) within additional nested `<apex:outputPanels>`. Any kind of active content can be problematic for the PDF render engine.

Without knowing exactly what your java applets are doing, I suspect there's little additional guidance anyone will be able to provide you with.